# Pass paramaters to animate jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like to pass paramaters in a custom function to animate specific parts. entirely not sure what im missing?

I've created a **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andeh/td9er67s/7/)**

```
function animate($class,$method,$value,$duration,$delay) {
    var delay_time = 0;
    $($class).each(function() {
        $(this).delay(delay_time).animate({
            $method : $value
        }, {
            duration: $duration
        });
        delay_time += $delay;
    });
}

animate(".container","width", 100, 300, 250);
```

The `$method` is what im trying to pass, which for some reason just doesnt want to work? What am i missing?

Comment: `$method : $value` You cannot use a variable to define an object property name like that, it will just end up making a property named `"$method"`

Comment: @PatrickEvans any reason as to why you cant?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, How ? Why ? `var val=100;
var obj={val:val};
console.log(obj);` => `Object {val: 100}`

Comment: Because it was never built into the JS engines that the browsers use to work like that. Though with ES6 you will be able to do it using computed properties, syntax like: `{[$method]:$value}` currently mostly only supported by chrome and firefox

Comment: @RayonDabre, yea that makes the property name literally `val` not what `val` contains, ie 100

Comment: @PatrickEvans, It took me a long time to read this...OP is trying to assign key using argument..Yes...That is not possible by the way OP is trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td9er67s/8/)**

You couldn't define an object as you do in `{$method: $value}`, But you could construct you object outside of animate method then just pass it :

```
var my_object = {};
my_object[$method]=$value;

$(this).delay(delay_time).animate(my_object,{duration: $duration});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function animate($class,$method,$value,$duration,$delay) {
  var delay_time = 0;
  $($class).each(function() {
    var my_object = {};
    my_object[$method]=$value;

    $(this).delay(delay_time).animate(my_object,{duration: $duration});
    delay_time += $delay;
  });
}


animate(".container","width", 100, 300, 250);
```

```css
.container {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0;
  background: #0f0;
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>show me</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>show me</p>
</div>
```